# what is JSON file on android?

Tags: android, json, encryption, dictionary

I am a beginner android programmer. I want to find and show details of a location(the location is user search) in the map on android. I should, for getting the branch details as a JSON encryption, send a HTTP request to a link(I have that link). but i don't know, Do a details of a location is a JSON file ever? How should i send the JSON to this link?

Please help me.Cheers.

Comment: One: Your question isn't very clear, especially the `Do a details of a location is a JSON file ever? ` part. Two: It seems like you're a little unclear on what JSON is. Try looking it up, and it's specifications. It is not a file. It is a String in a particular format

Comment: I don't know how can i find details a location, like telephone number or address or... . I want, you give me a link or document for that, i understand how can find details a location and how can i send a JSON to the a link. Thanks dear

Answer (score 1):

**JSON**, short for *JavaScript Object Notation*, is a lightweight computer data interchange format. [JSON](http://json.org/) is a text-based, human-readable format for representing simple data structures and associative arrays (called objects).

If you requested to send web service, use JSON like any String value.

Something  like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:boom="http://boomi.com/services/boomiServices">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <boom:GetSearchUrlsRequest>
        <boom:classifiedCnr>-5183511</boom:classifiedCnr>
        <boom:stepId>1</boom:stepId>
        <boom:cnc/>
        <boom:cnu/>
        <boom:session/>
        <boom:os/>
        <boom:clientVersion/>
        <boom:connectdCNR/>
        <boom:urlRequest>
            <boom:urlId>554175</boom:urlId>
            <boom:searchFlag>1</boom:searchFlag>
            <boom:resType>2</boom:resType>
            <boom:urlResponseStatus>200</boom:urlResponseStatus>
            <boom:urlResponseRawData>{"message":{"text":"OK","code":0,"version":"1.1.1"},"businesses":[{"rating_img_url":"http://media1.ct.yelpcdn.com/static/201012164084228337/i/ico/stars/stars_4.png","country_code":"US","id":"Jw-ENQw-OGGwpM3nA3ywqw","is_closed":false,"city":"Chester","mobile_url":"http://mobile.yelp.com/biz/Jw-ENQw-OGGwpM3nA3ywqw","review_count":2,"zip":"19013","state":"PA","latitude":39.859610500000002,"rating_img_url_small":"http://media3.px.yelpcdn.com/static/20101216418129184/i/ico/stars/stars_small_4.png","address1":"1450 Providence Road","address2":"","address3":"","phone":"6108728100","state_code":"PA","categories":[{"category_filter":"hotels","search_url":"http://www.yelp.com/search?find_loc=1450+Providence+Road%2C+Chester+19013&amp;cflt=hotels","name":"Hotels"}],"photo_url":"http://media3.ct.yelpcdn.com/bpthumb/2sQIFjLw_m-_RWNWcagONg/ms","distance":0.25479599833488464,"name":"Best Western Widener Hotel &amp; Suites","neighborhoods":[],"url":"http://www.yelp.com/biz/best-western-widener-hotel-and-suites-chester","country":"USA","avg_rating":4.0,"longitude":-75.359901899999997,"nearby_url":"http://www.yelp.com/search?find_loc=1450+Providence+Road%2C+Chester+19013","reviews":[{"rating_img_url_small":"http://media3.px.yelpcdn.com/static/20101216418129184/i/ico/stars/stars_small_4.png","user_photo_url_small":"http://media3.px.yelpcdn.com/upthumb/WdbHns2wmpNr9R7LgAj-9w/ss","rating_img_url":"http://media1.ct.yelpcdn.com/static/201012164084228337/i/ico/stars/stars_4.png","rating":4,"mobile_uri":"http://mobile.yelp.com/biz/Jw-ENQw-OGGwpM3nA3ywqw?srid=uXxAyIYEkLp8nWncoY3OjA","url":"http://www.yelp.com/biz/best-western-widener-hotel-and-suites-chester#hrid:uXxAyIYEkLp8nWncoY3OjA","user_url":"http://www.yelp.com/user_details?userid=DMwp6ZDmshHRPeQVrYGoqQ","text_excerpt":"I was pleasantly surprised by the cleanliness and amenities of this hotel and attribute it to its newness. This is actually a very, very nice hotel with...","user_photo_url":"http://media3.px.yelpcdn.com/upthumb/WdbHns2wmpNr9R7LgAj-9w/ms","date":"2010-09-20","user_name":"Amy B.","id":"uXxAyIYEkLp8nWncoY3OjA"},{"rating_img_url_small":"http://media3.px.yelpcdn.com/static/20101216418129184/i/ico/stars/stars_small_4.png","user_photo_url_small":"http://media3.px.yelpcdn.com/upthumb/tONwL7U5hpighYDC6ap0AQ/ss","rating_img_url":"http://media1.ct.yelpcdn.com/static/201012164084228337/i/ico/stars/stars_4.png","rating":4,"mobile_uri":"http://mobile.yelp.com/biz/Jw-ENQw-OGGwpM3nA3ywqw?srid=toAvvSjQvSGaLbPkrqURxg","url":"http://www.yelp.com/biz/best-western-widener-hotel-and-suites-chester#hrid:toAvvSjQvSGaLbPkrqURxg","user_url":"http://www.yelp.com/user_details?userid=JDgAAy73XoGJK4S1Z0UHAA","text_excerpt":"I have to be honest here and say the number one reason we stayed at this hotel was because they were able to give us a Best Western employee discount rate....","user_photo_url":"http://media3.px.yelpcdn.com/upthumb/tONwL7U5hpighYDC6ap0AQ/ms","date":"2009-09-15","user_name":"Amita R.","id":"toAvvSjQvSGaLbPkrqURxg"}],"photo_url_small":"http://media3.ct.yelpcdn.com/bpthumb/2sQIFjLw_m-_RWNWcagONg/ss"}]}</boom:urlResponseRawData>
        </boom:urlRequest>
        <boom:urlRequest>
            <boom:urlId>554176</boom:urlId>
            <boom:searchFlag>1</boom:searchFlag>
            <boom:resType>2</boom:resType>
            <boom:urlResponseStatus>200</boom:urlResponseStatus>
            <boom:urlResponseRawData>{"ResultSet":{"totalResultsAvailable":"21","totalResultsReturned":"10","firstResultPosition":"1","ResultSetMapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/broadband\/?q1=Chester%2C+PA+19013tt=widener+universitytp=1","Result":[{"id":"60691839","Title":"Widener University University College","Address":"1 University Pl","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 499-4282","Latitude":"39.861463","Longitude":"-75.355743","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.01","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-60691839-widener-university-university-college-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-60691839-widener-university-university-college-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=1+University+Pl+Chester+PAgid1=60691839","Categories":""},{"id":"61242738","Title":"Widener University-Safety Department","Address":"1 University Pl","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 499-4201","Latitude":"39.861463","Longitude":"-75.355743","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.01","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-61242738-widener-universitysafety-department-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-61242738-widener-universitysafety-department-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=1+University+Pl+Chester+PAgid1=61242738","BusinessUrl":"http:\/\/widener.edu\/","BusinessClickUrl":"http:\/\/widener.edu\/","Categories":{"Category":{"id":"96925802","content":"Colleges  Universities"}}},{"id":"60694608","Title":"Widener University Graduate Programs","Address":"1 University Pl","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 499-4384","Latitude":"39.861463","Longitude":"-75.355743","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.01","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-60694608-widener-university-graduate-programs-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-60694608-widener-university-graduate-programs-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=1+University+Pl+Chester+PAgid1=60694608","Categories":""},{"id":"12169550","Title":"Widener University","Address":"One University Pl.","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 499-4000","Latitude":"39.861463","Longitude":"-75.355743","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.01","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-12169550-widener-university-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-12169550-widener-university-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=One+University+Pl.+Chester+PAgid1=12169550","BusinessUrl":"http:\/\/www.widener.edu\/","BusinessClickUrl":"http:\/\/www.widener.edu\/","Categories":{"Category":[{"id":"96925802","content":"Colleges  Universities"},{"id":"96927134","content":"All Entertainers"},{"id":"96928448","content":"High Schools"},{"id":"96928449","content":"School Districts"}]}},{"id":"60693733","Title":"Widener University Schools  Colleges","Address":"1 University Pl","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 499-1101","Latitude":"39.861463","Longitude":"-75.355743","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.01","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-60693733-widener-university-schools-colleges-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-60693733-widener-university-schools-colleges-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=1+University+Pl+Chester+PAgid1=60693733","Categories":""},{"id":"61242762","Title":"Widener University","Address":"1 University Pl","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 876-7300","Latitude":"39.861463","Longitude":"-75.355743","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.01","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-61242762-widener-university-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-61242762-widener-university-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=1+University+Pl+Chester+PAgid1=61242762","Categories":{"Category":[{"id":"96925834","content":"Grocery Stores"},{"id":"96926008","content":"Bookstores"},{"id":"96928176","content":"Drug Stores"},{"id":"96935005","content":"Department Stores"},{"id":"96937229","content":"Greeting Cards"}]}},{"id":"60693305","Title":"Widener University Schools  Colleges","Address":"1 University Pl","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 499-4302","Latitude":"39.861463","Longitude":"-75.355743","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.01","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-60693305-widener-university-schools-colleges-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-60693305-widener-university-schools-colleges-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=1+University+Pl+Chester+PAgid1=60693305","Categories":""},{"id":"12183728","Title":"Wolfgram Memorial Library","Address":"1 University Pl","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 499-4087","Latitude":"39.861463","Longitude":"-75.355743","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.01","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-12183728-wolfgram-memorial-library-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-12183728-wolfgram-memorial-library-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=1+University+Pl+Chester+PAgid1=12183728","BusinessUrl":"http:\/\/widener.edu\/","BusinessClickUrl":"http:\/\/widener.edu\/","Categories":{"Category":{"id":"96925746","content":"Libraries"}}},{"id":"49610605","Title":"Psychological Services Center of Widener Universit","Address":"1606 Walnut St","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 499-1261","Latitude":"39.862089","Longitude":"-75.358895","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.18","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-49610605-psychological-services-center-of-widener-universit-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-49610605-psychological-services-center-of-widener-universit-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=1606+Walnut+St+Chester+PAgid1=49610605","Categories":{"Category":{"id":"96927514","content":"Mental Health Clinics"}}},{"id":"12183711","Title":"Dtd Enterprises Incorporated","Address":"701 E 12th St","City":"Chester","State":"PA","Phone":"(610) 499-1734","Latitude":"39.858733","Longitude":"-75.355063","Rating":{"AverageRating":"NaN","TotalRatings":"0","TotalReviews":"0","LastReviewDate":"","LastReviewIntro":""},"Distance":"0.18","Url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-12183711-dtd-enterprises-incorporated-chester","ClickUrl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-12183711-dtd-enterprises-incorporated-chester","MapUrl":"http:\/\/maps.yahoo.com\/maps_result?q1=701+E+12th+St+Chester+PAgid1=12183711","BusinessUrl":"http:\/\/stonehenge4stone.com\/","BusinessClickUrl":"http:\/\/stonehenge4stone.com\/","Categories":{"Category":{"id":"96930525","content":"B2B Masonry"}}}]}}</boom:urlResponseRawData>
        </boom:urlRequest>
        <boom:urlRequest>
            <boom:urlId>554177</boom:urlId>
            <boom:searchFlag>1</boom:searchFlag>
            <boom:resType>2</boom:resType>
            <boom:urlResponseStatus>200</boom:urlResponseStatus>
            <boom:urlResponseRawData>{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$gm":"http://base.google.com/ns-metadata/1.0","xmlns$g":"http://base.google.com/ns/1.0","xmlns$batch":"http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch","id":{"$t":"http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets"},"updated":{"$t":"2011-03-02T12:10:34.868Z"},"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Items matching query: (widener university) [location:@+039.86134300000-075.35566300000 +1mi]"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"http://base.google.com"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets/batch"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets?alt\u003djson-in-script\u0026q\u003dwidener+university\u0026start-index\u003d1\u0026max-results\u003d10\u0026bq\u003d+%5Blocation%3A%40%2B039.86134300000-075.35566300000+%2B1mi%5D"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Google Inc."},"email":{"$t":"base@google.com"}}],"generator":{"version":"1.0","uri":"http://base.google.com","$t":"GoogleBase"},"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":"0"},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":"1"},"openSearch$itemsPerPage":{"$t":"10"}}}</boom:urlResponseRawData>
        </boom:urlRequest>
    </boom:GetSearchUrlsRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

where `<boom:urlResponseRawData>` is JSON data